# E0349 Error while Extending istream to support a Person class

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I tried with and without `#include <iostream>` `#include <string>` or even `using namespace std` and nothing changed. The parameters must be references. When trying to run the code I receive the following error: `E0349 no operator ">>" matches these operands` in line 9.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

//Extending istream to support the Person class
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, Person & p) {
    is >> p.getName() >> p.getAge();
    return is;
}

//Extending ostream to support the Person class
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, Person & p) {
    os << "[" << p.getName()<<"," << p.getAge()<<"]";
}

int main() {
    Person *pOne = new Person();
    cout << "Person1's name is: " << pOne->getName() << endl;
    cin >> *pOne;
    getchar(); //Just to leave the console window open
    return 0;
}
```

Code from Person.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
private:
    string name;
    short age;
public:
    Person();
    virtual ~Person();
    Person(string, short);
    string getName();
    short getAge();
};
```

And here the code from Person.cpp:

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Person::Person()
    :name("[Unassigned Name]"), age(0)
{
    cout << "Hello from Person::Person" << endl;
}

Person::~Person()
{
    cout << "Goodbye from Person::~Person" << endl;
}

Person::Person(string name, short age)
    :name(name), age(age)
{
    cout << "Hello from Person::Person" << endl;
}

string Person::getName()
{
    return this->name;
}

short Person::getAge()
{
    return this->age;
}
```

The first `>>` in line 9 right after `is` is underlined red. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community.

Comment: What do the `getName()` `getAge()` functions return? Post a [mcve] as required here please.

Comment: getName() returns the string member variable name and getAge the short member variable age.

Comment: Are these returned as references? Otherwise there could not any input be received with those functions.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Put that code into your [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53902587/edit) please!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow but thanks for the annotation.

Comment: How do I change the code that getName() and getAge() return references though?

Comment: You probably shouldn't change it. Does your person class have corresponding setter functions also? Again, post a [mcve] showing all relevant code please.

Comment: @clever_coding: changing the accessor functiins to return a non-`const` reference amounts to adding a `&` behind the type. However, doing so would be a rather unclever thing to do: with that you’d expose the implementation details of the class. You are much better off reading the values into function local variables and updating them via suitable accessor functions (assuming reading them is successful: by convention failed reads don’t update the entity being read).

Comment: I'm not sure. Have a look at the rest of the code I just added please.

Comment: BTW, heap allocations in C++ need to be matched with heap deallocations. As doing so is cumbersome most objects are allocated on the stack or as part of an object taking care of their life-time. The code snippet you posted has a memory leak which can easily be avoided by having the object reside on the stack.

Comment: Does your class need a `virtual` destructor? Why? You need to learn about passing by `const&` (where appropriate) as passing objects by value can often lead to inefficient code. With your class the input function could construct a new object with the proper values and assign this to object being read.

Comment: Uhm okay, but what do I have to type to "read the values into function local variables and updating them via suitable accessor functions"

Comment: Time to research: there isn’t much point in me writing the code as you wouldn’t really learn from that and I don’t need to practice writing this kind of C++ code.

Comment: I'm researching right now so thanks for the help, I'm just beginning to teach myself c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that operator>> needs something it can *alter*. The return value of a function like `getName` is not such a thing.

Here's how you normally do this which is to make operator>> a friend function so that it can directly access the internals of the `Person` class.

```
class Person
{
    // make operator>> a friend function
    friend std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, Person & p);
private:
    string name;
    short age;
public:
    Person(string, short);
    string getName();
    short getAge();
};

//Extending istream to support the Person class
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, Person & p) {
    is >> p.name >> p.age;
    return is;
}
```

Not the only way though. Here's another approach that doesn't need to make anything a friend function. It uses temporary variables and then makes and assigns a Person object from those temporary variables.

```
//Extending istream to support the Person class
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, Person & p) {
    string name;
    short age;
    is >> name >> age;
    p = Person(name, age);
    return is;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you really helped me out there!